# Button moves down when text inside gets longer than the width of the button

Tags: html, css

I have a few buttons square buttons with text in.
When the text gets too long in a button, it automatically continues on the second line. Great. However, the button also moves down a bit and isn't aligned vertically with the others any longer. The more lines the text inside the button becomes, the further down the button moves.

Why is this happening, and obviously: how can I solve it?

The important html:

```
<button class="squareButton">
  Just some text
</button>
<button class="squareButton">
  Text that spans over more than 1 line
</button>
<button class="squareButton">
  Text that spans over 3 lines even has a bigger space
</button>
<button class="squareButton">
  Short text
</button>
```

The CSS:

```
.squareButton {
   height:150px;
   width:150px;
   position: relative;
}
```

A small codepen with this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNZmdd?editors=1100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to the square button class. This will make sure all buttons are aligned correctly.

```css
.squareButton {
   height:150px;
   width:150px;
   position: relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<button class="squareButton">
  Just some text
</button>
<button class="squareButton">
  Text that spans over more than 1 line
</button>
<button class="squareButton">
  Text that spans over 3 lines even has a bigger space
</button>
<button class="squareButton">
  Short text
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was fast! I'll accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.squareButton {
   height:150px;
   width:150px;
   position: relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```